# Maven deploy plugin/shade plugin: don't deploy uber jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm trying to both build an uber jar using the maven shade plugin (to build a docker image) and also deploy the project jars to a maven repository. I do not want to deploy the uber jar to the maven repo. Therefore, either I need to be able to exclude a particular file from the maven deploy plugin, or, make the maven shade plugin put the uber jar in a different location so it is not picked up by the deploy plugin.

Is either of these two things possible?

Comment: If you are creating a uber jar via maven-shade-plugin than it will be deployed to the repository. If you don't like to be deployed than just don't create it....What is the problem with this?

Comment: I want to include it in a docker image which is deployed to a docker registry. There is no point in uploading the uber jar to maven.

Comment: Is this s a single module build or does this build having multiple modules?

Comment: multi module build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two profiles: the default profile with shade plugin, and the other profile for deploy - without shade plugin. The deploy profile should also contain repository for deployment.

Comment: This is an interesting idea - unfortunately I guess it means executing the build twice which kind of sucks... but I don't see any other way. Thanks!